# Best way of triggering to delete a row from database if 'date` is 'today'?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I made a Diary at http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/agenda which can have Events for specific dates. You can add an event using the form located here: http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/evenementform

As you can see I have 3 fields 'Datum, Van & Tot' (translation: Datum = date, Van = From, Tot = till)
If the time on that specific date expires I would like to run a script which deletes that specific row from the database.

I searched on google and found a few things like MYSQL Trigger and PHP cronjob, but I don't know if there's an easier way to do this? or how to do it exactly.

My database structure looks like this:

```
agenda // diary
- - - - // not added the whole structure.
idagenda
titel
waar
www
email
activated
....
....

agendadatum // diary dates
- - - - - -
id
datum
van
tot
idagenda
```

as you can see I'm using a join to add more dates to one event.
How could I trigger the datetime to delete the rows from the db if the date = today?

NOTE: I am using the Codeigniter framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set a [hook](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html). And use a function like

```
$this->db->where('tot <', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$this->db->delete('agendadatum');
```

My codeigniter is a bit rusty but that query should remove all "old" entries on EVERY page load. So if you're going for high traffic this will not hold up.

Running a cronjob every hour/day is probably the "cleanest" way. This will require you to set a where condition on all selections of agendadatum that forces the "tot" date to be in the future. Else it's possible you see expired entries.

Edit:

From what I can gather if you define your hook like:

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
                              'class'    => '',
                              'function' => 'delete_old_entries',
                              'filename' => 'agenda.php',
                              'filepath' => 'hooks',
                              'params'   => array()
                          );
```

And create a file named `agenda.php` in application/hooks which looks like:

```
<?php
function delete_old_entries() {
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->database();
    $query = $CI->db->query(" DELETE FROM agendadatum WHERE tot < NOW(); ");
}
```

It should work. However this is pieced together from what I could find and untested. So it might work, it might not. But something along these lines should do the trick even if it isn't this.

Comment: I could try the codeigniter option first. if that works, it's ok :)

Comment: I don't really know how to make that hook, even with the docs open :) Can I just add that on the function `public function agenda()` which is the 'home page' for my events view.

Comment: i will definitely try this now :)

Comment: How could I also delete the row from the agenda table that affects the agendadatum row?

Comment: For that I would suggest using foreign keys properly within the database and allowing MySQL to clean any linked data.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

```
CREATE TRIGGER deleteRows AFTER UPDATE,INSERT ON myTable
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DELETE FROM myTable WHERE Datum = NOW()
END;
```

Comment: This is a mysql way so I think I have to do this in mysql? actually I'm happier with a php way.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a built-in [Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events-overview.html) that basically allows you to run arbitrary SQL code at scheduled times. You could purge your database once a day for instance.

However, I know from your other question that you are hosting your project on a shared host, and, unfortunately, shuch hosts often disable the feature. Check out this manual page to find out whether the feature is active on your server.

Comment: The answer from @EWit solved my problem. Using Codeigniter hooks was the easiest way.